# How long to allow between arriving and getting a train from Stockholm Arlanda?

Tags: airports, stockholm

Arriving off a flight from Edinburgh (both which currently arrive into terminal 5), how much time should I allow before aiming to catch a train from Arlanda Central? I have an EU passport and may or may not have checked luggage.

Comment: Are you asking how much time will you need to reach the train station after stepping off the plane? Is this so you can safely book a train ticket?

Comment: @JoErNanO Yes. I'm heading beyond Stockholm, and would rather get the infrequent direct trains, but it seems a bit tight.

Comment: So the train you're aiming for will leave from Arlanda C rather than one of the two stations for the Arlanda Express train?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes. Sorry, I'd forgotten there were multiple stations at Arlanda.

Comment: You might want to add all these details in your question. ;)

Answer (score 4):

In terminal 5 it depends on what gate you arrive at. The F gates are quite a walk from security. The entrance to Arlanda Central is located in Sky City between Terminal 5 and Terminal 4. I would count on 5-15 minutes to get out of arrivals - then another 10 minutes to get to the station so with some marginal 30 minutes should be fine. With checked luggage it is much harder to tell. Normally luggage appears soonish at Arlanda but it is not possible to be sure about this.

[This page](http://www.ifly.com/stockholm-arlanda-airport/terminal-map) claims somewhat shorter walking times.